# Adding HSTS and X-FRAME configuration in JSF application

Tags: jsf, x-frame-options, hsts

There was a recent scan on an application developed using JSF framework, the scan suggested that we should add hsts and x-frame header. I only know Java but completely new to the JSF framework, please where can I add this configurations??

Comment: @Kukeltje yes I read about the filters but couldn't find detail explanation on how to go about it.

Comment: Try this: let me know if it works, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371755/clickjacking-filter-to-add-x-frame-options-in-response#11371897 then I can create an answer related to jsf (which it effectively it is not but)